# Symfony 2 authentication with (doctrine) Entity

Tags: authentication, doctrine-orm, symfony

I think I've tried all code in all posts about authentication with
(doctrine) Entity in [Symfony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) 2. And I can`t make it work.
When I use in_memory provider all works fine.
I'm using the PR8.

My `security.yml`

```
security:
    encoders:
        Partners\FrontendBundle\Entity\User:       plaintext
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: FrontendBundle:User, property: username }
        #        in_memory:
        #            users:
        #                sergi:        { password: boo123, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:         /.*
            form_login:      true
            anonymous:       true
            logout:          true
    access_control:
        - { path: /docs.*, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: /control.*, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: /.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
```

My User entity

```
<?php
    namespace Partners\FrontendBundle\Entity;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    use Partners\FrontendBundle\Repository\UserRepository;
    /**
     * @orm:Entity(repositoryClass="Partners\FrontendBundle\Repository
    \UserRepository")
     * @orm:Table(name="users")
     */
    class User implements UserInterface
    {
        /**
         * @orm:Id
         * @orm:Column(type="integer")
         * @orm:GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        protected $id;
        /**
         * @orm:Column(type="string", length="32", unique=true)
         */
        protected $username;
        /**
         * @orm:Column(type="string", length="255", unique=true)
         */
        protected $email;
        /**
         * @orm:Column(type="string", length="128")
         */
        protected $password;
        /**
         * @orm:Column(type="string", length="128")
         */
        protected $organization;
        /**
         * @orm:Column(type="string", length="128")
         */
        protected $contact;
        /**
         * @orm:Column(type="string", length="16")
         */
        protected $phone;
        /**
         * @orm:Column(type="string", length="10")
         */
        protected $cid;
        /**
         * @orm:Column(type="smallint")
         */
        protected $status;
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
        public function setId($id)
        {
            $this->id = $id;
        }
        public function getUsername()
        {
            return $this->username;
        }
        public function setUsername($username)
        {
            $this->username = $username;
        }
        public function getPassword()
        {
            return $this->password;
        }
        public function setPassword($password)
        {
            $this->password = $password;
        }
        public function setEmail($email)
        {
            $this->email = $email;
        }
        public function getEmail()
        {
            return $this->email;
        }
        public function setPhone($phone)
        {
            $this->phone = $phone;
        }
        public function getPhone()
        {
            return $this->phone;
        }
        public function setContact($contact)
        {
            $this->contact = $contact;
        }
        public function getContact()
        {
            return $this->contact;
        }
        public function setOrganization($org)
        {
            $this->organization = $org;
        }
        public function getOrganization()
        {
            return $this->organization;
        }
        public function setCid($cid)
        {
            $this->cid = $cid;
        }
        public function getCid()
        {
            return $this->cid;
        }
        public function setStatus($status)
        {
          $this->status = $status;
        }
        public function getStatus()
        {
          return $this->status;
        }
        /**
         * Implementing the UserInterface interface
         */
        public function __toString()
        {
            return $this->getUsername();
        }
        public function getRoles()
        {
            return array('ROLE_USER');
        }
        public function eraseCredentials()
        {
            return false;
        }
        public function getSalt()
        {
            return $this->getId();
        }
        /**
         * equals.
         *
         * @param UserInterface $account
         * @return bool
         */
        public function equals(UserInterface $account)
        {
            if ($account->getUsername() != $this->getUsername) {
                return false;
            }
            if ($account->getEmail() != $this->getEmail) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The UserRepository

```
<?php
    namespace Partners\FrontendBundle\Repository;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements
    UserProviderInterface
    {
        const CREATED  = 0;
        const ACTIVE   = 10;
        const INACTIVE = 20;
        /**
         * loadUserByUsername.
         *
         * @param string $username
         * @return Partners\FrontendBundle\Entity\User
         */
        public function loadUserByUsername($username)
        {
            return $this->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));
        }
        function loadUser(UserInterface $user)
        {
            return $user;
        }
        function loadUserByAccount(AccountInterface $account)
        {
            return $this->loadUserByUsername($account->getUsername());
        }
        public function supportsClass($class)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

When I fill the login form the error in the $error = $this->get('request')->getSession()->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR); is:

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception
\BadCredentialsException' with message 'Bad credentials' in /var/www/
inspiring/trunk/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/
Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:66 Stack
trace: #0 /var/www/inspiring/trunk/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/
Component/HttpFoundation/SessionStorage/NativeSessionStorage.php(81):
session_start() #1 /var/www/inspiring/trunk/Symfony/app/cache/dev/
classes-53824.php(284): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\SessionStorage
\NativeSessionStorage->start() #2 /var/www/inspiring/trunk/Symfony/app/
cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php(1151): Symfony\Component
\HttpFoundation\Session->start() #3 /var/www/inspiring/trunk/Symfony/
app/bootstrap.php.cache(109): appDevDebugProjectContainer-
>getSessionService() #4 /var/www/inspiring/trunk/Symfony/app/cache/dev/

classes-53824.php(1553): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection
\Container->get('session') #5 /var/www/inspiring/trunk/Symfony/app/
cache/dev/classes-53824.php(1544): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle
\RequestListener->initializeSession(Object(Symfony\Component
\HttpFoundation\Request), true) #6 /var/www/inspiring/trunk/Symfony/
app/cache/dev/classes-53824.php(1214): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle
\RequestListener->onCoreRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel
\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #7 /var/www/inspiring/trunk/Symfony/vendor/
symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Debug/
TraceableEventDispatcher.php(49): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher
\EventDispatcher->triggerListener(Object(Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle
\RequestListener), 'onCoreRequest', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel
\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #8 /var/www/inspiring/trunk/Symfony/app/
cache/dev/classes-53824.php(1146): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Debug
\TraceableEventDispatcher->triggerListener(Object(Symfony\Bundle
\FrameworkBundle\RequestListener), 'onCoreRequest', Object(Symfony
\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #9 /var/www/inspiring/
trunk/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes-53824.php(1734): Symfony\Component
\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('onCoreRequest',
Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #10 /var/
www/inspiring/trunk/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache(411): Symfony
\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher-
>dispatch('onCoreRequest', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event

\GetResponseEvent)) #11 /var/www/inspiring/trunk/Symfony/app/
bootstrap.php.cache(400): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-
>handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1) #12 /

var/www/inspiring/trunk/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/
FrameworkBundle/HttpKernel.php(35): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel
\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request),
1, true) #13 /var/www/inspiring/trunk/Symfony/app/
bootstrap.php.cache(576): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpKernel-
>handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)

#14 /var/www/inspiring/trunk/Symfony/web/app_dev.php(15): Symfony
\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component
\HttpFoundation\Request)) #15 {main}
```

I don't know where the problem can be.

Comment: How are you passwords stored in the database? Plaintext?

Comment: Yes, I stored in plaintext while developing. Now I'm in production and encripted them.

Comment: Salting would have been my next guess ;-)

Comment: May I ask: why are you using the same class as both the user repository and the user provider?

I followed your example and did the same, and later it made it extremely difficult for me to figure out how to use a second database for the users.

Comment: I couldn’t pass the EntityManager to the user provider using service arguments, because arguments 2 and 3 of the EntityRepository constructor are `mixed class`and `ClassMetadata classMetadata`, and I couldn’t figure out what to use in `services.yml`.

I ended up not subclassing EntityRepository, using the EntityManager as the sole constructor argument, and passing it as `@doctrine.orm.mymanager_entity_manager`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally somebody helped me.
The issue is that I wasn't using any salt to create the password, and in the getSalt function of the User class I was returning the ID.

The password is generated like this (in the controller):

```
$factory = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory');
$encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
$pwd = $encoder->encodePassword('your_random_password', $user->getSalt());
$user->setPassword($pwd);
```