# Symfony2 authentication with Entity without salt

Tags: authentication, doctrine-orm, symfony

I tried to do like in this topic: [Symfony 2 authentication with (doctrine) Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408134/symfony2-authentication-with-doctrine-entity)
And I don't know what to do with the getSalt() method, I don't want to use salt so I try getSalt() returning null but it doesn't work.
Please, can anyone help me?

PS: Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The salt is a string (usually derived from a one-way hashing function) that is prefixed the password before the chosen encoding function is applied. It can be a fixed string if you like, and it can also be an empty one.

```
public function getSalt() {
    return ''; // Could also be 'mysalt'
}
```