# Authentication Fails showing 'Bad Credentials' in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to implement authentication in my application, I am authenticating the users against the database.For test purpose, i am implementing it using plain text algorithm and my password is saved as plain text in database.

This is my secuirity.yml

```
 security:
encoders:
    System\VmsBundle\Entity\VmsUsers:
        algorithm: plaintext


role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:
    administrators:
        entity: { class: SystemVmsBundle:VmsUsers, property: username }

firewalls:
    admin_area:
        pattern:    ^/entrydetails
        http_basic: ~
        form_login:
          check_path: login_check
          login_path: login
          use_forward: true
          always_use_default_target_path: false
          default_target_path: /
          target_path_parameter:  _target_path
          use_referer: true     

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Below is my login action

```
 public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // get the login error if there is one
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR))
    {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(
            SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
        );

    }
    else

    {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);

    }

    return $this->render(
        'SystemVmsBundle:VmsUsers:login.html.twig',
        array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error'         => $error,
        )
    );
```

And my entity

```
 <?php

 namespace System\VmsBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

 class VmsUsers implements UserInterface, \Serializable
 {

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $salt;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $email;

/**
  * @var boolean
 */
private $isActive;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->isActive = true;
    $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
}
/**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return VmsUsers
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return VmsUsers
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return VmsUsers
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password =$password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

     public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

     public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->salt,
            $this->password,
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->salt,
            $this->password,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return VmsUsers
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return VmsUsers
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

It is always showing 'bad credentials' error. When i checked the posted data in firebug,it is showing correctly. But the error still persists! Any idea?

Can anyone kindly explain the ways to authenticate  a user against a database in symfony?A step by step method will be very helpful,since i am very new to symfony ways of doing things!!

Comment: check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408134/symfony-2-authentication-with-doctrine-entity

Comment: I was in same situation once. It was showing 'Bad credentials' even if everything is right. Then I found that the username,password input name has to be '_username' & '_password'. I know it's silly but see if it helps you.

Comment: Now i know, its all because of the salt!I got it worked in plaintext algorithm without salt. But not with md5 algorithm and hashing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i got i worked with md5 algorithm.My password is encrypted and stored in the database.

In security.yml

```
 security:
     encoders:
         System\VmsBundle\Entity\VmsUsers: md5
```

Salt is generated as uniqid and using that,password is generated.In the controller

```
   $factory = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($entity);

            $pwd = $encoder->encodePassword($entity->getPassword(), $entity->getSalt());
             $entity->setPassword($pwd);

             $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
```

All thanks to this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408134/symfony-2-authentication-with-doctrine-entity)

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your encoder like this:

```
encoders:
    System\VmsBundle\Entity\VmsUsers: plaintext
```

Your login_path should be a route, and not a /login, unless you named the route /login?

Both login_path and check_path require defined routes.

Define them as such:

```
# security.yml
form_login:
      login_path:  login
      check_path:  login_check

# app/config/routing.yml
login:
    path:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: YourBundle:YourController:login }
login_check:
    path:   /login_check
```

Comment: Tried,but no difference!

Comment: Any chance you can post your VmsUsers entity ?

Are you implementing all the required methods:

getRoles(),
getPassword(),
getSalt(),
getUsername(),
eraseCredentials()

=

Comment: You dont seem to have the method eraseCredentials(), an empty method is fine.     /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }
Also, please fix it so /login is a route and not a URL

Comment: Added! Still can not login!

Comment: login_path does not work as route for me btw, it has to be a url.

Comment: What if you remove the salt from your constructor? I think that's generated for you.

Comment: @Anyone login_path is 'login' which is directed to login action of controller in routing.yml. Do u want me to remove the salt?

Comment: @DencyGB I know about the path, I'm using annotations for routing and for some reason that fails for me, but that's another story. Yes, I want you to remove the salt from your constructor and try again. In my (LDAP variant) login, I never set that manually and it always changes. My guess is that by changing the salt, something goes wrong in validating the credentials.

Comment: In between..should check_path be directed to any action?Currently i hav'nt set any!

Comment: As far as I know you should point it to an existing empty action in your controller (no body). Due to the kernel events it will never be triggered but is required to use for routing.

Comment: @Anyone removing salt form construct method results in the following errror"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'salt' cannot be null"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45795/discussion-between-dency-g-b-and-anyone)